# Selenium and nodeJs

Tags: java, node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have an importable jar that captures performance of Web page. Use case is like, if you have an existing selenium automation code you can simply call the method that will invoke the jar and record performance.

Now I have a requirement to get the audit data from Chrome Performance Lighthouse in a json format that can only be done installing NPM on client machine, then I have to install performancelignthouse via npm like:

```
npm install -g lighthouse
lighthouse --output=json --output-path=./report.json https://airhorner.com/
```

This way I can get the JSON data.

So here my question , is there any way to run the second line of code via Chromedriver without installing node on client machine?

Thanks in advance......

Comment: I assume this is a browser plugin. If you can get it to print its output to console you can use driver.get_log

Comment: Do you need to execute **lighthouse** without node and npm?

Comment: yes @JRichardsz

Comment: are you able to download node?